# Add permissions to readers (DevOps Web Portal)

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

I have a public Azure DevOps project, and I want to allow everyone to add Work Items.

However, adding the **Readers group as a member of Contributors** for the permissions doesn't change anything, and I can't find *"Add Work Items"* but only the *"Delete Work Items"* toggle for changing its own Readers perms so I am really stuck here.

The contributors perms:
[image]

Having to add every mail account to allow people to add work items isn't possible in my situation (Game Engine project) so I really have to find a solution.

Comment: Even Stakeholder access level has permission to add work items now. What exactly does a user experience when trying?

Comment: I have tried that, but unfortunately you can't inherit the group Readers to the group Stakeholder so everyone is able to work items, for a reason I ignore. So they just don't have any perms other than what allows Readers.

Answer (score 1):

Usually each projects would have teams defined with the team members. So if you have a team defined then add the team to the contributors list.

Comment: Unfortunately I did already, but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: See if the same members\team are added as Readers. Azure DevOps might be using inherited permission. Try removing the contributors from readers list.